# Hystrix executionException and failedExecutionException in fallback function

Tags: java, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I'm using the HystrixCommand class to provide circuit-breaker functionality for my code.
I've created the following class that encapsulates function execution with fallback:

```
class FunctionWithFallback<T> extends HystrixCommand<T> {

    private final Supplier<T> function;
    private final Function<Throwable, T> fallback;

    protected FunctionWithFallback(final Supplier<T> function, final Function<Throwable, T> fallback,
                                   final String groupKey, final String commandKey) {
        super(HystrixCommand.Setter
                .withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey(groupKey))
                .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(commandKey)));
        this.function = function;
        this.fallback = fallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected T run() {
        return function.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected T getFallback() {
        return fallback.apply(getExecutionException());
    }
}
```

I got stuck with what exception I should provide to the fallback.
There are two methods in HystrixCommand that return the exception: `getExecutionException` and `getFailedExecutionException`

I've read the javadoc, but it's still not completely clear to me which one I should use in the fallback function to get original exception thrown from supplied function.

What would you recommend and why?